# How can I "insert into tab1 values (select * from tab2, ...)" with Oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
Insert into table1 
values ((select * from table2), sysdate, 'open', Null, null);
```

This is what I'd like to run. How can I write this query?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any effort trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries used with `VALUES` clause are required to return only one row. If your query returns more than one row, you can rewrite it as follows:

```
insert into table1 select t2.*, sysdate, 'open', null, null from table2 t2;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! So if i'm to insert data from one db to another can I use the below? create database link link1 connect to User1 identified by abc123 using 
'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=some_host)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYSID)))' ;


insert into table1@link1 select t2.*, sysdate, 'open', null, null from schema.table2 t2;

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't do that. This is a normal distributed transaction.